# Flutter Riverpod select property in StreamProvider

Tags: flutter, state, state-management, riverpod

I am trying to achieve something like this:

```
final myStreamProvider = StreamProvider<User>((ref) {
  return MyStreams.getUserStream;
});

// rebuild the widget only if user's name changes
final name = ref.watch(myStreamProvider.select((value) => value.name));
```

I am just giving a small example above. Basically, I want the widget to rebuild only if the name of the user changes. But in this case, my widget rebuild even if other properties of the user changes.

How do we use "select" method with StreamProvider in Riverpod?

Comment: The "value" in a streamprovider is wrapped in an AsyncValue.  You need to use something like .valueOrNull on it, then ?.name should work.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to select the stream value, then call the .when (or .whenData etc.) in order to deal with it

In your case:

```
final myStream = ref.watch(someStreamProvider.select(
      (theStream) => theStream.when(
         data: (data)=>data,
         error: (error, stack) => 'There was no name',
         loading:() => 'Loading Name'),
    ),
);
```